# What do "be driven" & "be strong" mean in this text?

Tags: word-meaning

> I absolutely love to travel whether it be domestic or international!  I have traveled all over the world for work and pleasure (Europe, UAE, Russia, Africa, Canada) but I still have quite a few places on my bucket list to visit!  I love wine almost as much as I love to travel :).  My friends and my mother mean the world to me! I would do anything for them and vice versa. I am a type A personality and can be **high strung** at times! I want someone who works hard and is driven but who knows how to balance their work and social/family life. I am not your typical girl. I do not date just to date and I do not go out on dates for a free meal. Pay attention to my preferences!

She says **high strung at time** and then she says she liked someone who is **driven** . Are all these idiom? Be driven and be strung?

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "can be high strung at times" means that she can be **nervous or easily upset**.  When she says she likes someone who is "driven" she means that she likes someone who is **motivated or determined**.

Comment: Something I think the OP might find useful: "High strung" is derived from the tendency of tightly-wound string or rope to break easily. "String" can be used as a verb which means to stretch from one point to another, and "strung" is the past tense version. It is not derived from the words "strong" or "strength."